# Suggestion for a flex game communication between entities

Tags: apache-flex, events, communication, entities

I'm currently developing a Flex game which is a kind of table and cards game. Thinking about developing other games using entities from this one, I chose for creating my entities decoupled from the game and even from other game entities. As a result, I'm currently using events for communication between my game entities.

Game entities, in my case, refers for example a player hand component which can receive a card, or send a card to another unknown component by a custom requesting and dealing events. For instance, the same can happens to a deck of cards holder component.

This approach appeared to be a good designer in the beginning, but after some time, my game controller class has a lot of event handler functions which started looking bad for me.

My current idea is to create a game event manager coupled with my game controller for handling events and cleaning the controllers code.

Finally, I'm not sure about my design decision exposed above, so I would like to know about you folks which communication design would be indicated for this kind of a game.

I hope this question answers can help others mind too.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lots of code in a controller isn't necessarily a bad thing. After all it mediates between a model and a the view, so that's where a lot of application logic will end up. If you are looking for something to help you structure things a little bit, check out the http://www.robotlegs.org/ framework.

Answer (score 0):

Can you break it up into several controllers classes?  In a tabbed application, I use a spearate controller for each tab.  Breaking down your application into sensible pieces won't be as cut and dry, but very possible.

One suggesetion might be:

- MainController - Handles the 'shell' of the game, such as application startup, menus, splash screens, etc...
- GameController - Handle state changes and user based events like taking turns, checking for win conditions, updating scores, etc...
- EntityController - Communication between your game entities (cards, decks, and hands?).

It's hard for me to make too many judgements with such little information about your game, but I hope you get the idea.

Also, if you want to cut down on boilerplate event handling code, I second the idea of using a framework.  I've heard good things about robotlegs, and have personally used Swiz on a couple projects.  Swiz has great, unobtrusive event mediation [swizframework.org](http://swizframework.org).